# Importing Images in SQL Server: Follow On

Tags: sql-server, image, dynamic, cursor

This is a follow on question to a dynamic sql solution that I found on Stack Overflow.  I would like to use the code model as used in a previous example.  The problem is that i am getting the following error:   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "ABC123.jpg" could not be bound and I do not understand why as the image names are indeed loaded.  I am at my wits end.  I feel that I am very close to making this solution work but cannot get beyond this issue.

Please find the sample code below:

```
declare AssetCursor cursor fast_forward for
    select Image_File_Name
        from Images

declare @sql nvarchar(4000)
declare @Image_File_Name varchar(50)

open AssetCursor      

while (1=1) begin
    fetch next from AssetCursor into @Image_File_Name

    if @@FETCH_STATUS<>0 break

    set @sql = N'UPDATE dbo.Images
                     SET Doc_Image = 
                         (SELECT * FROM 
                              OPENROWSET(BULK N''C:\MyImages\' + cast(@Image_File_Name as varchar(50)) + N'.JPG'', SINGLE_BLOB) AS img)
                              WHERE Image_File_Name = ' + cast(@Image_File_Name as varchar(50))

    exec(@sql)   
end /* while */

close AssetCursor
deallocate AssetCursor
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

WHERE Image_File_Name = '' + cast(@Image_File_Name as varchar(50)) + ''

where '' is two single-quotes, not a double quote. You're building a dynamic SQL so a literal string within it needs another layer of apostrophies

Comment: If I do this then I get:

Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '.JPG', SINGLE_BLOB) AS img)
                              WHERE Image_File_Name =  ' + cast(@Image_File_Name as varchar(50))'

    exec(@sql)   
end /* while */

close AssetCursor
deallocate AssetCursor
'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
Incorrect syntax near '.JPG', SINGLE_BLOB) AS img)
                              WHERE Image_File_Name =  ' + cast(@Image_File_Name as varchar(50))'
'.